# Powershell Read-host input from CSV

Tags: powershell

Im trying to get this script to work by instead of me manually inputing sysnames that I can put the servers into csv and script it and give an output of results

It just sits at the prompt waiting for manual input

```
$csvpath = E:\Tsm.csv
$SvcName = '*tsm*scheduler*'
$dataset = import-csv -path $csvpath
$row = ($dataset | where{$_.hostname -eq $SysName})
$SysName = Read-Host -prompt "Enter the target computer name: "
$Tsm = Get-Service -ComputerName $SysName | Where {$_.name -Like $SvcName}
Write-Host "Service :" $Tsm.DisplayName
Write-Host "Status :" $Tsm.Status
Write-host "Start Type :" $Tsm.StartType

If ($Tsm.StartType -ne 'Automatic')
{
    Write-Host "Setting service startup type to Automatic."
    Set-Service -InputObject $Tsm -StartupType Automatic
}
If ($Tsm.Status -ne 'Running')
{
    Write-Host "Starting the service."
    Start-Service -InputObject $Tsm
}

$Tsm2 = Get-Service -ComputerName $SysName | Where {$_.name -Like $SvcName}
Write-Host "Service :" $Tsm2.DisplayName
Write-Host "Status :" $Tsm2.Status
Write-host "Start Type :" $Tsm2.StartType
Export-Csv C:\TestOutput.csv$csvpath = E:\Tsm.csv
```

Comment: Ummm.. what exactly is the problem? _"trying to add CSV for import it just don't script and read it"_ is not clear...

Comment: sorry if i was not clear - It just sits at the prompt waiting for manual input

Comment: A couple things immediately jump straight away:    `$csvpath = E:\Tsm.csv` needs to be enclosed in quotes (    `$csvpath = "E:\Tsm.csv"` ).       `Export-Csv C:\TestOutput.csv$csvpath = E:\Tsm.csv` - this line is incorrect

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get what you want. Basically you shouldn't be using `Read-Host`, or only use it when you want the prompt and manual waiting.

A couple of points:

```
# this line uses the $SysName variable, which is asked for in the next line. 
# so it will not work correctly.
$row = ($dataset | where{$_.hostname -eq $SysName})       

# if you do not want the waiting and pause on screen, remove this line.
# That's the standard way Read-Host works.
$SysName = Read-Host -prompt "Enter the target computer name: "
```

One possible solution:

```
param(
    [switch]$manual
)

if($manual){
    $SysName = Read-Host -prompt "Enter the target computer name: "
}else{
    $SysName = "value or variable"
}
```

With this solution you can call your script using `.\script.ps1` for auto-solution or `.\script.ps1 -manual` for the `Read-Host`.

Comment: OK so i remove that line, what do I put for $SysName =

Comment: @sysadmin42 What should it equal? Where is the value meant to be coming from?

Comment: from the cvs file

Comment: @sysadmin42 That's really unhelpful without knowing the contents of the CSV file

Comment: Its just hostnames